# How to tell "OfType()" to ignore inherited classes?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, inheritance, oftype

In my WPF application, I have the following line:

```
var windowList = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().ToList();
```

This is returning 2 results. These results have the following types:

1. `Microsoft.Crm.UnifiedServiceDesk.Desktop`
2. `System.Windows.Window`

I *only* want the 2nd result to be returned. However, since result #1 inherits `System.Windows.Window`, it is included in the result.

Is there a way to restrict the `OfType<T>()` function to **NOT** return inherited classes, or do I have to accomplish this another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `OfType` on its own to achieve this, but you can use that with a `Where` clause afterwards:

```
var windowList = Application.Current.Windows
    .OfType<Window>()
    .Where(w => w.GetType() == typeof(Window))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @Sinatr I just tried it in my application with `Application.Current.Windows.Where(w=> w.GetType() == typeof(Window)).ToList();` and I get the error "Internal error in the expression evaluator", so I think it is. But the good news is, Jon Skeet's answer works perfectly!

Comment: WindowCollection is an IEnumerable but not a generic IEnumerable<T>. That's why you need to use OfType before you use Where.

Comment: @Sinatr Can't be that stupid.. I didn't know `WindowCollection` was not an `IEnumerable<T>` and now I do! lol. I was wondering why I couldn't call `Application.Current.Windows.ToList()`...